# MySQL Query, Date Range From "Blacklist"

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I have 2 databases. One is `properties` and the other is `dates`. In `dates` I have associated the land_id and a date (In YYYYMMDD format) which means that the date is *not available*.

I need to formulate a query that a user can specify a start and end date, and then choose a property for which dates are available (not in the `date` database). How do airline and hotel websites do this kind of logic? I was thinking about taking the date range and picking all days in between and doing a query where the dates do not match and ordering it by number of results, but I can see how that could easily turn into an intense query.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `land_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=44 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `dates`
--

INSERT INTO `dates` (`id`, `land_id`, `date`) VALUES
(43, 1, '20100526'),
(39, 1, '20100522'),
(40, 1, '20100523'),
(41, 1, '20100521'),
(42, 1, '20100525');
```

Comment: store dates in the data types exclusively designed for dates: `date`

Comment: zerkms, thanks for the reply, but this doesn't address the logic required to pull the correct properties ?:)

Comment: sorry for editing my answer so often, i think it should be ok now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the Dates as `VARCHAR` will make it harder to write a query. I suggest
to save the dates as `DATE` and use the following query.
This should help:

```
SELECT * FROM dates WHERE date NOT BETWEEN '<start_date>' AND '<end_date>'
```

It selects the dates not being between the given range.

I found a solution in the [MySQL 5.1. reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in order to make it work with `VARCHAR`,too:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y%m%d') as real_date 
FROM dates WHERE real_date NOT BETWEEN '<start_date>' AND '<end_date>'
```

Or

```
SELECT DATE(date) as real_date 
FROM dates WHERE real_date NOT BETWEEN '<start_date>' AND '<end_date>'
```

btw: `<start_date>` and `<end_date>` are placeholders. Insert the concrete dates there (in format YYYY-MM-DD).